# FIX connection does not reconnect at start time

Tags: fix-protocol

I am trying to troubleshoot a FIX connection that has been acting up the last few weeks. It is set to logout every day at 23:30 and log back in at 23:35. It logs out at the correct time but then makes no attempt to reconnect at StartTime. If for whatever reason the connection fails during the day, it also does not reconnect. I'm not sure what is wrong here. Other sessions do not have this issue. Any ideas what could be going wrong?

```
[DEFAULT]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
ReconnectInterval=10
HeartBtInt=30

[Session]
LogonDay=Sunday
LogoutDay=Friday
StartTime=21:35:00
EndTime=21:30:00
ResetOnLogon=N
ResetOnLogout=Y
RefreshOnLogon=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=N
```

Here are the last messages that come through. There is no logon attempt made at 23:35

```
8=FIX.4.4|9=65|35=0|34=2170|49=***|52=20210415-21:29:43.484|56=***|10=042
8=FIX.4.4|9=65|35=5|34=2171|49=***|52=20210415-21:30:00.507|56=***|10=029
8=FIX.4.4|9=65|35=5|34=2099|49=***|52=20210415-21:30:00.546|56=***|10=041
```

Comment: Which QuickFIX variant are you using? C++, Java, .NET? Which version?

Comment: Put a comment in your OnLogon override and see if it logs...

Comment: I am using the Python version of QuickFIX version 1.15.1.1

Comment: Did you try using `LogonTime` and `LogoutTime` as the doc suggests? http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html